# Clique e "Desclique" em botão com jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho um Botão criado apenas em HTML e CSS, e preciso que se alguém clicar nele, um bloco `<div>` altere seu `background-color`. Com isso talvez:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button_on-off').click(function(){
        $(".bloco").css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)');
    });
});
```

Mas quero que quando o botão estiver ON ele fique transparente e quando o botão estiver OFF ele fique com cor.

Usando JQuery.

Bem, já deixei tudo comentado e preparado no jsfiddle para você me ajudar.

Não ligue para o código HTML ou CSS, acredito que não vá precisar, é necessário trabalhar apenas em js.

Basta abrir em uma nova Guia : http://jsfiddle.net/c49fjwmz/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa, vi que a pergunta já foi respondida mas queria contribuir com uma alternativa que foca no clique do seu input checkbox, e não no div:

click: toda vez que clicar no checkbox ele executa o código abaixo:

```
$("#myonoffswitch").click(function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
    var color = isChecked ? 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)' : 'red';
    $("#bloco").css('background-color', color);
});
```

Obs: vi que no comentário de outra resposta você solicitou o seguinte: "sempre que o botão esteja ON haja uma variavel "conexao = true" e quando esteja OFF haja "conexao = false""

Nesse caso você pode usar o seguinte código:

```
$("#myonoffswitch").is(":checked");
```

Ele irá retornar `true` caso esteja ON (checked) e `false` caso esteja OFF. Sempre que você precisar dessa informação basta executar aquele código, sem a necessidade de instanciar uma variável global.

Espero ter contribuído,

até.

Answer (score 7):

Seu código inclui um checkbox que guarda se o estado do botão é "on" ou "off". Você pode usar esse estado para determinar a cor. Por exemplo:

```
$('#button_on-off').click(function(){
    var cor = $('#myonoffswitch')[0].checked ? 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)' : 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)';
    $("#bloco").css('background-color', cor);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c49fjwmz/3/

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu certo! Me resta uma duvida, se eu querer, por exemplo que sempre que o botão esteja ON haja uma variavel "conexao = true" e quando esteja OFF haja "conexao = false", para outros fins, você poderia complementar para mim por favor ?

Comment: O toggleClass do jquery tambem resolveria bem esse assunto